# Exception, errors handling, best practice in WebApi Core

Tags: c#, error-handling, asp.net-web-api

I'm making my `WebApi` project.

My logic is, the controller didn't see data. It only triggers a service that returns objects to it. My simple method from `TaskService` looks like this:

```
public Task TakeTaskByUser(int taskId, string userId)
{
    var task = this.GetItem(taskId);

    if (task != null)
    {
        if (task.ApplicationUserId != null)
        {
            throw new TaskTakenByAnotherUserException();
        }

        task.ApplicationUserId = userId;
        task.StartTime = DateTime.Now;

        this.context.Entry(task).State = EntityState.Modified;
        this.context.SaveChanges();

        return task;
    }

    return null;
}
```

As you can see, in this method I try to find `Task` and attach Foreign Key to `User` by his `UserId`. If `Task` is already taken by another user, I throw a custom exception.

In my controller, `Action` looks like this:

```
[HttpPut("{taskId}/{userId}")]
[Authorize(Roles = "Developer, Manager")]
public IActionResult TakeTaskByUser([FromRoute] int taskId, [FromRoute] string userId)
{
    try
    {
        var task = this.taskService.TakeTaskByUser(taskId, userId.ToString());
        if (task != null)
        {
            return this.Ok(task);
        }

        return this.NotFound();
    }
    catch (TaskTakenByAnotherUserException)
    {
        return this.ValidationProblem();
    }
}
```

Is using a `try-catch` block in a controller good practice? Is using any exceptions in `WebApi` good, or I should use the method posted in [this article](https://www.exceptionnotfound.net/the-asp-net-web-api-exception-handling-pipeline-a-guided-tour/) (I like **Level 1**, seems easy and fun)?

How do I deal with errors that **I know** that can appear when someone sends a request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exceptions are pretty costly so as a general rule of thumb [they should be avoided](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/exceptions/best-practices-for-exceptions). Especially when we talk about REST endpoint where response time is crucial.

Also, to my taste you're messing up [command-query separation principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command%E2%80%93query_separation) in your code. I would have rewritten it roughly like this

````
[HttpPut("{taskId}/{userId}")]
[Authorize(Roles = "Developer, Manager")]
public IActionResult TakeTaskByUser([FromRoute] int taskId, [FromRoute] string userId)
{
    var task = this.taskService.GetTask(taskId);
    if (task == null)
        return this.NotFound();
    var taskValidationResult = this.taskValidator.Validate(task);
    if (!taskValidationResult.IsSuccess)
    {
        //handle validation failure
    }

    task = this.taskService.TakeTaskByUser(task, userId);

    return this.Ok(task);
}
```
````

Comment: I like that method to avoid exceptions. I will try it, thanks!

Comment: @Bohdan Stupak how would you handle validation failures? Ignore silently, wrap as  some kind of response or perhaps throw an exception ?

Comment: I would return some kind of response to be consistent with `return this.NotFound()` couple lines above. I've omitted the code because the mapping of validation result to response code might be verbose and irrelevant for the case.